# A good video editor/creation tool

Tags: video-editor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Video editing on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5911/video-editing-on-ubuntu)

I'm looking for a good video editor/creation app for Ubuntu. Something similar to that on Windows would work just fine for my purposes. I would prefer something that could add in titles and transitions. Any suggestions would be appreciated! Oh, and the video file type doesn't make a huge different for my need either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theres AVIDemux, and LIVEs. LIVEs is pretty cool.

Comment: I'm liking openshot, but I'll give LIVEs a try too.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried pitivi? IIRC it's installed by default on 10.04, and should be in the repositories for other versions.