# Alternatives to dvd-slideshow

Tags: software-recommendation, video-editor, slideshow

I'm currently using [dvd-slideshow](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/dvd-slideshow) to create video files containing slideshows with sound, transitions and titles, and I'm quite fond of the command line approach for this kind of task. Is there any good alternatives to dvd-slideshow for this kind of task, if so which? Or should I stick with dvd-slideshow?

As mentioned I appreciate using the command line for this kind of task but it's not a necessary – I'd be happy with a good GUI too. Also, I'd appreciate further options and customizability than what dvd-slideshow allows for. Finally, I'd appreciate answers with *arguments* for a certain application or *comparisons* between certain applications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## photofilmstrip

[image]

The version in Software Center is v1.4.1.  v1.5 is available from the [authors website](http://www.photofilmstrip.org/4-1-Download.html)

Looking at Sourceforge - it is actively being updated - currently v1.99, so expect v2.0 soon.

It can create photofilms via its GUI.

It can create photofiles via command line as well -

```
photofilmstrip-cli /?
```

Why do I like it? - its very simple - drag and drop and click render.  Simple as that.

Comment: It is also available in Ubuntu: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=PhotoFilmStrip

Comment: I was unaware of this - NICE -

Answer (score 2):

[Imagination](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/imagination) is a lightweight and simple DVD slide show maker for Linux and FreeBSD written in C language and built with the GTK+2 toolkit.

To install:

```
sudo apt-get install imagination
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Why do you link to the source code page on launchpad?

Comment: shows releases and bugs if interested