# how to create own video

Tags: video, video-editor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Video editing software options?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5911/video-editing-software-options)

I have to create my own video as a promo of our technical event.How to create it with ubuntu 11.04?   Which software is ideal for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Pitivi has put a lot of work to make a decent video editor that has power and simplicity for the needs of you and me ;)

Check it here: `http://www.pitivi.org`

The ppa is here: `ppa:pitivi/stable`

If you find that this doesn't match your needs say so and we will find something else! Gl!