# Is there any working, usable video editing software for ubuntu?

Tags: video-editor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Video editing software options?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5911/video-editing-software-options)

Is there any decently stable video editing software for Ubuntu, that won't crash at every mouse click and that you can actually *use* for doing things that you need? (as opposed to for the sake of testing it)

I've tried out pitivi and cinelerra but they are completely unstable (they both crash very often) besides having very poorly designed interfaces...

Is there any better option or are we still stuck to Windows and Mac OS for even the most basic (but real-life) video editing?

Even something as basic as Avidemux would be fine in many situations (not all) if only it worked (i.e. if not rendered completely useless by its bugs).