# Movie maker **simple** alternative

Tags: software-recommendation, video, editing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Video editing software options?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5911/video-editing-software-options)

Is there an alternative program in Ubuntu for Microsoft Movie Maker?
What I (..well.. my girlfriend..) need is NOT something for multi-track, HD, DV import, blur effects, etc... but something to e.g. add rotating funny textual effects, "stars of light", transitional effects... I think you get the idea ;-)

Comment: Indeed all the options on that questions were too "advanced" software. After my own review the closest software for what I was looking for is [ffDiaporama](http://ffdiaporama.tuxfamily.org/), a slideshow creator that allows also embedding of videoclips.