# sony handicam can`t download to shotwell

Tags: downloads

i`m trying to download videos from my older (mini tape) storage camcorder using a usb cable.connected to my laptop,running latest version ubuntu. I thank anyone who helps ahead of time. Thanks.

Comment: What kind of errors are you having? Is the camcorder recognized and mounted by the computer, i.e. can you see the icon in the desktop when you connect it?

Answer (score 1):

Tape handycams should be captured in a capture software like kdenlive, openshot or any other non linear editing system (NLES). For that purpose you should either use the proper USB or Firewire (iEEE1394) cable.

You can't simply plug the camcorder and "download" the video files. Try kdenlive but there are a few other good alternatives as you can see in the answers to this question: [Video editing software options?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5911/video-editing-software-options).

Good luck!

Comment: I sure did try that no luck. any more ideas?

Comment: Oh sorry, you didn't mention that in your question. Ok, let's know if your camera is well recognized by your computer by dropping lsusb in a terminal and tell us the results as an edit to your question. Additionally, if you have more information as the error messages, etc. Please provide it with details. kdenlive is good enough to video capture from USB but first we need the camera correctly installed. One more thing: Does your HandyCam feature a FireWire Connector? You have better chances if use the iLink (iEEE1394) cable. Thank you.