# Remove extra noise from ffmpeg video

Tags: sound, ffmpeg, noise

I am using the following command to record the audio and video:

```
ffmpeg -loglevel warning -y -f v4l2 -s 544x288 -i /dev/video0 -vstats -vstats_file '/home/2014-05-13T07-18-37/left_cam-stats' -f pulse -name 'Unknown source 0' -i alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo -filter lowpass -f pulse -name 'left_mic 0' -i alsa_input.usb-046d_0823_D81A0330-00-U0x46d0x823_1.analog-stereo  -f pulse -name 'right_mic 1' -i alsa_input.usb-046d_0823_4B709030-00-U0x46d0x823.analog-stereo  -f pulse -name 'default 0' -i default  -f mpegts -crf 20 -r 24 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vcodec libx264 -vprofile baseline -t 02:00:00 -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -map 2:0 -map 3:0 -map 4:0 /home/left_cam.mp4
```

It record both audio and video from different devices.

But the audio comes with the horrible noise (feed back). I want to remove that noise form the recording.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: For background noise removal see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/391798/video-editing-app-for-lowering-background-noise-while-evidentiating-slow-voice and http://askubuntu.com/questions/429480/how-to-improve-the-sound-quality-of-an-mp3-speech-file

Answer (score 2):

Using **Sox** you can you can reduce noice.

Sox can be installed with :

```
sudo apt-get install sox
```

To use sox, you can follow this article at [www.zoharbabin.com](http://www.zoharbabin.com/how-to-do-noise-reduction-using-ffmpeg-and-sox/).

Or:

For direct use with ffmpeg you can try following code.

Source :[ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2091899)

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -vcodec libx264 -crf 24 -preset slow -filter:v hqdn3d=4.0:3.0:6.0:4.5 -acodec aac -strict experimental -ab 192k output.mp4
```

Comment: please explain which flags in the command are enabling noise reduction.