# Separate audio and video to edit them and then join together

Tags: sound, video

I need to make a video but changing the voice(frequency) of the speaker. 
Some program should may be able to separate audio and video. Then i would edit and after all join audio and video together again.

I have programmes like audacity, kdenlive, etc but none of them seems useful.

Is there any program to do something like that? Any help to solve this will be welcome.

Comment: Changing your voice how ? Dubbing over the top, adding effects, what are you wanting to do exactly ? You might want to try Ubuntu studio or a more full featured recording app.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen i said i need to change the frequency, what is unclear?

Comment: I dont understand if you are looking for a way of changing the recording ie add effects or if you are trying to fix a problem ie the recording you are making is distorted and you want to normalize it. Sound recording can get complicated see https://wiki.linuxaudio.org/apps/categories/effects_processors

Comment: @bodhi.zazen no, i want to record a video but changing the voice frequency of the speaker. I wonder if there is a program that allows one to save separately audio and video, for example. Then i could edit both separately and join them with another program (like kdenlive). Do you understand? Thanks for the time

Comment: I am sure there are several options available to you but some of the apps start to become specialized fast. Take a look at ubuntu Studio or similar - http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/6-linux-distros-designed-artists-musicians-editors/ I like KXstudio - http://kxstudio.linuxaudio.org/

Comment: The "problem" you might have with a standard Ubuntu install is that Ubuntu is not optimized for Audio / Video editing, so depending on your system you may start to have distortions. Ubutnu studio and Kxstudio are optimized for what I think you want both with tuning the operating system as well as installed apps / tools. These things are done for you in KXstudio - https://wiki.linuxaudio.org/wiki/system_configuration . You certainly can install recording apps and see what happens, but you are likely to get up and running faster with Ubuntu Studio

Comment: You can try Openshot , one of my favorate apps, but you may need to record and edit a sound track with audacity.http://www.openshotvideo.com/2009/07/audio-editing-with-openshot.html . If openshot and audacity do not do what you want -> off to Ubuntu Studio for you ;)

Comment: https://audacity.wonderhowto.com/how-to/turn-male-voice-female-voice-with-audacity-424309/

Comment: How to separate audio from video for audio processing [see my answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/392230/3940). In step 2. use audacity's **pitch shift** filter instead.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen ohh, i thought i would be easier..I will try with kxstudio

Comment: @Takkat i am not sure if it is the same. You mean a way to separate audio and "movie" from a video and then join them together?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen only to be sure we understood each other. You say that those programms could be used for separate audio and "movie" from a video and then join them together? Isn't it?

Comment: @HernanProust: it is the same. To process audio we need to separate the audio tracks from the video in any case. Video processing software do that internally.

Comment: Openshot or similar and audacity are IMO the best tools on a vanilla Ubuntu install. If you need more then that or if you have problems with distortion or skipping you will need to move to Ubuntu studio or KXstudio.