# Ubuntu software that can edit .mov files created in Adobe after effects

Tags: video, adobe

I need a bit of assistance from the Ubuntu community. I'd like to know if there is a Linux version of Adobe after effects that I can use to open a .mov  video file that was created using Adobe after effects.  I need to  open the video files smiler to the way after Adobe after effects would, the video clips need to opened in a file format structure.

i.e.
File 1) logo
File 2) Text, 
File 3 Social
and so on...

The file is a 11 second video intro I purchased but need to edit the logo and text file.

I've already tried Pitivi, Blender, Openshot but none of them above the video clip files to replace text and logo.  I'm not sure that blender will even edit .mov files?

I've searched off and on for weeks without any luck.

I hope I can find and alternative for this.

I do not use windows period so switching to windows for this 11 second video is pretty much out of the question.

I truly thanks everyone in advance for any and all assistance

Roger

Comment: .mov is a container format rather than a codec so it depends on what is inside it. .mov is supported since a very long time in Blender (at least since 2010) as long has you have a FFmpeg enabled build of Blender. Nowadays we use avconv in Ubuntu so it might be a bit more than just installing Blender.

Comment: check here http://askubuntu.com/questions/5911/video-editing-software-options

Answer (score 4):

I think the best answer to your question could be Kdenlive, that's the only what I can suggest for Ubuntu/Linux.

Kdenlive is an intuitive and powerful multi-track video editor, including most recent video technologies.

[image]

And there are two ways you can install it from:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kdenlive
```

This will install the latest release that is in Ubuntu repos and it's 0.9.6, but if you wish to install the latest official release 0.9.10 from Kdenlive official source releases:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sunab/kdenlive-release
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kdenlive
```

Comment: Please note that if you use plain Ubuntu (with Unity) or any non-KDE variant installing kdenlive will also force installation of a few dozen libraries and other dependencies. Not a huge problem, but worth mentioning anyway.

Comment: @Erathiel even though it was developed originally for KDE nowadays it runs on different desktop environments and it's included in Ubuntu Software Center also.

Comment: It does, true. I've never said it wouldn't run on different desktops, just that it needs to install quite a lot of additional libraries, which may (or may not) be an issue for some people. Just that :)