# Video editing software

Tags: software-recommendation, video, video-editor

So I have finally figured out how to record videos without any frame drops and such. Now my problem is the video editing software. 

So far, every one that I have tried has just not worked. Everyone who has answered questions like mine have said that the best ones to use are openshot and Kdenlive, neither of which are working for me. Openshot crashes frequently and Kdenlive just freezes.

What I am looking for is either a way to fix said crashes and freezes, or some other program for editing, that doesn't have to be fancy, as long as it works fine. I don't need any special features, all I need is to be able to cut and merge audio and video.

Comment: check this also http://askubuntu.com/questions/609565/ubuntu-software-that-can-edit-mov-files-created-in-adobe-after-effects/609575#609575

Comment: @L4Z0R_ there are also shotcut, blender and lwks

Answer (score 0):

Just use [pitivi](http://www.pitivi.org/):

It's simple clean easy to use. Install it:

```
sudo apt-get install pitivi
```

[image]

[**Here**](http://filmora.wondershare.com/video-editor/free-linux-video-editor.html) you can find a list of other software you can give a try.