# A simple GUI to create a video file from an audio and an image file?

Tags: sound, software-recommendation, video

Is there any software under active development that provides me with a simple GUI to combine an audio file with an image file to create a resulting video file that I can upload, e.g. to YouTube?

I know there are simple command-line options but still, I prefer a graphical user interface where I can visually drop the files. :-)

Comment: There is [photfilmstrip](http://www.photofilmstrip.org) which should be in the default repositories and allows dia shows with audio.

Comment: Thanks but still too complicated and with too many effect options.

Answer (score 2):

[Kdenlive](https://kdenlive.org/)! ☺ Awesome tool to edit video. Simple to understand. You may have to [add their repository](https://kdenlive.org/download/) to have the latest version. In [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5911/video-editing-software-options) you have a list of video editing software for Linux. I've tried a lot, and the one that has worked best always has been Kdenlive.

Comment: Thanks for your inspiration! I found [Flowblade](https://github.com/jliljebl/flowblade). Have you tried this one, too?

Comment: No. Now that I have one that works and I know how to use I'm not really looking for alternatives :) What's their specialty?

Comment: For me it's just more stable and reliable than Kdenlive. I never got warm with it.

Answer (score 0):

An embedded album cover in an audio file is the most common example of what you want. You can check with `ffprobe` - part of `ffmpeg` - that the embedded image is the "video" track of the file.

A video player like `mpv` plays the audio with the image as a still image, which I assume is what you want.

Therefore, the easiest answer is to treat your image like an album cover and handle the task with one of the music tagger programs. I would recommend `EasyTAG` for this.You can drag and drop the image file to the highlighted audio file and save the results.

Comment: Thanks! However, I am not sure if your solution works for me. I want to create a video file to upload it to YouTube.

Comment: This info should be part of the question! I assumed that you just want a fullscreen background for playing audio files. If you want to upload to YT, a conversion like `ffmpeg -i my_song.m4a -hide_banner -acodec copy -vsync 2 -pix_fmt yuv420p my_song.mp4` would do the trick, but it defeats the intention to do everything via GUI.

Comment: Thanks! I edited my question to make clear that I want to upload it to YouTube.