# Video editor for YouTube

Tags: software-recommendation, video-editor

Which is the best video editor for making YouTube videos in 18.04?

Something like adding in the video - texts and symbols ( or emojis ), and things around that line. Also, some method to export output in a format compatible with YouTube standards.

Comment: "Best" according to what? Can you please reword including objective criteria like needed features?

Comment: " for making YouTube videos" why is that a criteria for "best"? I would assume ALL are capable of editing a video that is a valid format for any on-line service.

Comment: I have seen YouTube videos adding text, emojis, symbols, flyout effect etc. I am sure people like us who view a lot of tech video understand what I mean by this question. Also, I remember some editor which allows us to export into file formats for YouTube. Thanks.

Comment: Let me stress again, "best" according to what? Some users might consider a video editor with lots of features to be the best. Others might prefer one which has just a few features but is easy to use. Unfortunately, AU is not a good fit for opinion based questions. However, if you have precise requirements then surely answers can be written that target those requirements specifically.

Comment: 'Best' is always a trigger point for eager AU close-voters but the question has some reasonably strict requirements for inclusions which are very specific. Hence I believe that the question should not be closed and certainly I would vote for reopen if it does get closed...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Video editing software options?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5911/video-editing-software-options)

Comment: I think 18.04 tag was appropriate. I was not hoping for a general answer. I was specific about the features I was looking for. Highlighted them too.

Comment: Version tags should be used only for version specific questions (e.g. problem specific only to that specific Ubuntu version), not just because you're using the version. Since 18.04 is the current LTS release it's very likely that any software which is still maintained would be available for this version. If you have found any software which used to work with older release, but not with 18.04, then edit your question and mention it explicitly.

Answer (score 8):

Personally I'd recommend DaVinci Resolve.

Although I've used Kdenlive a ton, DaVinci is really high brow and yet free.

you can download it here:

http://www.danieltufvesson.com/makeresolvedeb

after that you can run it. I suggest watching one or two videos on it's different workflow.

they kinda reinvented the workflow and you don't have to use "their" workflow, but I honestly gotta say it's better than the workflow you'll typically have under apps like kdenlive or Premiere and saves alot of time so it's worth learning.

Comment: Looks nice. I am downloading. Will try it and report :)

Comment: Thanks for the deb file.

Answer (score 5):

Apparently Cinelerra GG / Flowblade / Natron / Shotcut / Lightworks are a much better solution then DaVinci Resolve and compatible with Ubuntu to boot (which isn't really the case for Davinci Resolve).

- [Cinelerra GG](https://www.cinelerra-gg.org/)
- [Flowblade](https://jliljebl.github.io/flowblade/)
- [Natron](https://snapcraft.io/natron)
- [Shotcut](https://shotcut.org/)
- [Lightworks](https://www.lwks.com/)
- [Blender](https://www.blender.org/download/)

These applications can be used together for a workflow, for example :

[Flowblade] -> [Natron]

Or all alone, for example :

[Cinelerra GG]

I haven't tried them but this is a much more appropriate answer given we're on ask ubuntu.

Comment: "best" tends to be 1 at most ;-)

Comment: huh. yeah i guess but in video editing (even on windows), you generally use severall apps together, not just one, like after effects to prepare footage and premire to cut it, for example. But I can edit  to leave only Cinelerra if you want.

Comment: Thanks for the options. Really appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 2):

The following are good options:

1. [Kdenlive](https://kdenlive.org/) : This is usually the most preferred video editing tool for linux with a bunch of features and a lot of customization options. See [the wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kdenlive) for more info.
2. [Openshot](https://www.openshot.org/): I have personally used this and it also does a good job. However I had some issues with it as it used to hang sometimes. But overall it has quite user-friendly interface and is very easy to learn.

Comment: Kdenlive looks nice. It is simpler as well. I have mostly used OpenShot, which is a bit out of scope for videos I plan to make. Nothing wrong in it, just too simple editor. I was also thinking about PiTiVi. Happy about the many suggestions I am getting here. :)

Comment: an underrated quality of kdenlive it that you can use all threads on your cpu when rendering/exporting a project but this feature is hidden and disabled by default, you need to go into the extra options when getting ready to render and type in your threadcount value, for example for me it's 12. and as a result of that my project renders 12 times faster which is much appreciated.