# Merge and edit two cell phone videos for youtube.com

Tags: software-recommendation, video, android, youtube

I have two cell phone videos the first 45 seconds and the second 30 seconds. I would like to merge them together and upload to youtube.com. I also need to insert introductory video leaders:

- a 3 second introductory clip "This is before repair"
- first video of 45 seconds
- a 3 second introductory clip "This is after repair"
- second video

What tools are available to create this youtube.com video in Ubuntu 16.04 (I also have Ubuntu 19.04 installed)?

**Note:** I didn't specify a video file format when I made the two videos on my cell phone but it is running Android 7 I believe.

Comment: I suggest that you consider *kdenlive*.

Comment: @chili555 Your advise is always great. I will check it out.

Comment: It looks like you want something that allows creating titles and credits. Alternately you can create two static images with the chapter titles (say white text on black background) and in the video editor insert them at the appropriate places and set them to display for 3 seconds each.

Comment: pitivi is another option. See this video for a tutorial for inserting titles: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QyPWq5_RhdE

Comment: An useful question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/5911/video-editing-software-options

Answer (score 1):

On my Ubuntu box I use [shotcut](https://shotcut.org/). It's a bit clonky for certain things, but it's powerful for a totally free (Open Source) software.

What you are asking is a matter of drag & drop each clip to the screen, then from the screen to the timeline. Make sure it works (click play) and then do Export. As you'll notice the interface is not 100% flowless, but in the end I have videos that work as is on YouTube.

IMPORTANT: make sure to get the latest and install it "by hand". Otherwise you're likely to get an old version (the authors generate new versions quickly and the one in Ubuntu is not being updated all the time.)

Comment: Thanks. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [AVIdeMux](http://avidemux.sourceforge.net/) for years, that is simple and fast editor for basic edits such as cut, merge, replace, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I'll add it to the list to review.